# Re-initialize a 3D spline surface using different control points

Tags: surfaces, interpolation, spline

I have a 3d spline surface is that is modeled with 65 points where the x,y,z position of each point is known.

I want to keep the surface shape, but have different x,y positions for my control points. How do I find the Z values for these new control points?

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about B-spline surface?  If yes, I don't think you can arbitrarily change the control points' x, y values while expect to keep the shape unchanged. You can only hope to keep the shape change to be within a certain tolerance.

Comment: Yes a B-spline. Yes, I hope to keep the surface shape pretty close to the original. How would I get the Z height of these new control points and keep the tolerance below some value?

Comment: How about sampling points on the surface followed by a constrained least square fitting to the sampled points with the new (x, y) values for control points as constraints?